# Comparision of two datagrids in WPF and displaying mistmatches in different color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Following are two Datagrids used by me and bound to DataTable.DefaultView of an SQLDataAdapter.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,215,0,0" Name="rResultGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="399" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LastOutput.Output1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"  Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,215,0,0" Name="rResultGrid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="381" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LastOutput.Output2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I want to compare the content of the above two grids and if any mismatch I would like to highlight the respective filed color.

Is there a best practice to be followed here?
Please help me.

Comment: First of all I'd guess as a bp is relocating such loginc into the/a viewmodel and defining something like a datarow class, that contains the datatable's columns as properties plus properties for matching information.